# Vim - mapping q only when not recording?

Tags: vim, macros

When not recording a macro, pressing `q` followed by a register begins recording a macro in that register.  Other commands are available too, e.g. `q:`, to open the command window.

When recording a macro, pressing `q` stops the recording.  In other words, the `q` mapping behaves differently whether or not a macro is being recording.  You can't nest one recording in another.

I want to remap `q:` when not recording a macro, but retain the regular behavior of `q` to stop a macro if currently recording.  A regular mapping doesn't quite work correctly -- if I am recording a macro and then press `q` there is a delay because Vim is trying to determine if I am going to follow it with a `:` to trigger the mapping.  I want the mapping to only ever apply if I am not recording a macro so this delay doesn't happen.  How can I detect this?

My use case is that I want `q:` to behave like `:q` and instead map `g:` to open the command window, since half the time I press `q:` I meant to press `:q`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found a solution, building on [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7006/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-im-recording-in-vimscript#answer-7016).

```
nnoremap <silent> q :<C-u>call <SID>SmartQ()<CR>
function! s:SmartQ()
  if exists("g:recording_macro")
    let r = g:recording_macro
    unlet g:recording_macro
    normal! q
    execute 'let @'.r.' = @'.r.'[:-2]'
  else
    let c = nr2char(getchar())
    if c == ':'
      quit
    else
      if c =~ '\v[0-9a-zA-Z"]'
        let g:recording_macro = c
      endif
      execute 'normal! q'.c
    endif
  endif
endfunction
```